# How to print in python the "right triangle pattern" (5, 54, 543, 5432, 54321)

Tags: python, while-loop

How to print following sequence of number by while loop in python?

```
5
54
543
5432
54321
```

Below I show my code:

```
while (i <= n):
    j = 1
    while (j <= 1):
        print(j,end='')
        j+=1
    print()
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i = 5
while i>= 1:
    j = 5
    while j >= i:
        print(j, end=" ")
        j -= 1
    i-=1
    print()
```

#try this code.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(5,0,-1):
   for j in range(5,i-1,-1):
      print(j, end = " ")
   print()
```